# ¿Porque no funciona ninguna media query en mi css?

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-5, mediaqueries

Estoy intentando hacer responsiva mi pagina web con media querys y bootstrap 5 pero parece haber algún tipo de conflicto. El caso esque las media querys no funcionan.
He probado simplemente a cambiar el color del footer a rojo, y no se que puede estar haciendo que falle.

Aquí mi HTML (`layout.blade.php`) y CSS:

```css
.body {
  padding: 20px;
}

._menu {
  background-color: #f7f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

._menu .img {
  width: 100px;
}

._bg-img {
  height: 65vh;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

._search-button {
  font-size: 20vw;
}

._nav-contacto {
  height: 8vh;
}

._contact-img {
  width: 15px;
}

a._link:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

._nav-contacto {
  font-size: small;
}

._div-azul {
  background-color: #2c88ee;
  height: 10vh;
  color: #f7f5f5;
}

._content {
  background-color: #f7f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

._appoint-banner {
  background-color: #2c88ee;
  width: 50vw;
  color: #f7f5f5;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

._appoint-banner ._appoint-p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

._appoint-banner ._appoint-button {
  background-color: #f7f5f5;
  color: #2c88ee;
}

._appoint-banner ._appoint-button ._appoint-img {
  width: 15px;
}

._img-bottom-div {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #f7f5f5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

._img-bottom-div ._img-bottom {
  width: 35vw;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

._img-bottom-div:before {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 70px 60px #f7f5f5;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 70px 60px #f7f5f5;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 70px 60px #f7f5f5;
}

._div-login {
  background-color: #2c88ee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

._form {
  align-items: center;
}

._form ._form-label {
  color: #f7f5f5;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
}

._form ._form-input {
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

._form ._submit {
  color: #131212;
  background-color: #f7f5f5;
}

._section {
  background-color: #f7f5f5;
}

._footer {
  background-color: #8e8b82;
}

._img-carou {
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

#NavsDiv {
  height: 65vh;
  background-color: #d0dff0;
  position: relative;
}

#map {
  width: 50vw;
}

@media all and (min-width: 576px) {
  ._footer {
    background-color: red;
  }
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

```html
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss','resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset(" /img/favicon-16x16.png ") }}">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY') }}&callback=initMap"></script>
  <title>ActiveLife Physio</title>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" id="NavsDiv">
    <img class="_bg-img" src="{{ asset(" img/imagebgmenu.jpg ") }}" alt="Background Image">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg p-0" id="NavTop">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-end">
        <div class="d-flex align-self-center w-75 _nav-contacto">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto h-75 _contact-top">
            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">¿Do you have any question?</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
              <img class="_contact-img" src="{{ asset('img/atimg.png') }}" alt="Contact link img"><a class="nav-link" href="#">+44 7837262871</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
              <img class="_contact-img" src="{{ asset('img/phone.png') }}" alt="Phone link img"><a class="nav-link" href="#">clinic@email.com</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex h-75" id="search">
            <input class="form-control w-75 me-1 py-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success w-25 me-1 py-2" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
          <div class="d-flex h-75">
            @if (Route::has('login')) @if (session('id_user') != null && session('id_user') != "")
            <button class="btn btn-light mx-1 p-1"><a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="_link w-75 h-75 text-center text-nowrap">Sign out</a></button> @else
            <button class="btn btn-light mx-1 p-1"><a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="_link w-75 h-75 text-center text-nowrap">Sign in</a></button> @endif @endif @if (Route::has('register'))
            <button class="btn btn-light mx-1 p-1"><a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="_link w-75 h-75 text-center text-nowrap">Sign up</a></button> @endif
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="align-self-center w-75 m-1 _menu">
      <div id="logo" class="d-flex"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo img" height="50vh">
        <h1>ActiveLife</h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('team') }}">Our Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('treatment') }}">Treatments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('more') }}">More Services</a>
        </li>
        @if (session('id_user') != null && session('id_user') != "")
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('request') }}">Request an appoitment</a>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Request an appoitment</a>
        </li>
        @endif

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about') }}">About us</a>
        </li>
        @if (session('role') == 4 || session('role') == 5)
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{  route('admin')  }}">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{  route('dashboard')  }}">Profile</a>
        </li>
        @elseif (session('role') == 6)
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{  route('dashboard')  }}">Profile</a>
        </li>
        @endif
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="_section">
    @if(session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
    @php session()->forget('status'); @endphp @endif @yield('content')
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center _content">
        <div class="d-flex align-self-center justify-content-evenly _appoint-banner">
          <p class="_appoint-p">We ensure out patients receive the best treatments.</p>
          @if (session('id_user') != null && session('id_user') != "")
          <button class="btn btn-light _appoint-button"><a class="_link" href="{{ route('request') }}">REQUEST AN APPOINTMENT</a><img class="_appoint-img" src="{{ asset("img/appointment.png") }}" alt="Appointment Request Image"></button> @else
          <button class="btn btn-light _appoint-button"><a class="_link" href="{{ route('login') }}">REQUEST AN APPOINTMENT</a><img class="_appoint-img" src="{{ asset("img/appointment.png") }}" alt="Appointment Request Image"></button> @endif
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
          <div class="_img-bottom-div"><img class="_img-bottom" src="{{ asset(" img/kinesio.jpg ") }}" alt="Kinesiotherapy image"></div>
          <div class="_img-bottom-div"><img class="_img-bottom" src="{{ asset(" img/maso.jpg ") }}" alt="Masotherapy image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="mt-auto _footer">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
      <div class="d-flex w-25">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex w-25">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Buscando soluciones solo he dado con los errores comunes (falta etiqueta meta, las media querys no estan al final del archivo css..). Pero en mi código no parece haber estos fallos.
Ah, también he probado a borrar la caché del navegador sin resultado.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Quizás te convenga más preparar un [mcve], pues al darle ejecutar a los snippets que dejaste en la pregunta, es difícil visualizar lo que comentas en la pregunta, además que dejaste el CSS y el HTML en snippets separados. Un saludo.

Comment: En tu @media has puesto :
```
@media all and (min-width: 576px).
```
Esto quiere decir que el contenido se va a mostrar cuando el ancho sea MAYOR a 576px. Es lo que queres?. Si lo que buscas es que el contenido se vea por ejemplo en celulares deberias poner : ```
@media all and (max-width: 576px).
``` Lo que tampoco veo en tu html es que lo hayas conectado con el archivo css por medio de la etiqueta link. Saludos!

Comment: Tu código funciona. Si queres comprobarlo podes editar el snippet, modificar  `(min-width: 576px)` por `(min-width: 876px)`, ejecutarlo.

Comment: Por cierto: no sé por qué estarás utilizando jQuery, pero desde la versión 5 de Bootstrap, ya no es necesario.

Comment: El JQuery lo utilizo para sacar mostrar un select con las horas disponibles en la fecha elegida.

Comment: Es curioso. Como esque el snippet funciona aquí pero a mi no se me cambia el color ejecutando el proyecto en local ni en el servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado con el comando npm run build en mi servidor. Ya se puede cerrar esta pregunta. Gracias a todos por la ayuda!.

Comment: Por favor no uses el area de respuestas para poner un comentario.

Comment: Si lo que describes realmente resuelve tu problema, esto debería considerarse la respuesta a tu pregunta. En unos pocos días podrás marcar tu propia respuesta como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Pero deberías evitar comentarios como _ya se puede cerrar esta pregunta_ y escribir la respuesta de manera clara para que pueda ser útil a quien en el futuro se vea en tu situación.